# What's so interesting behind the "delete your account" meme?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I mean, I just recently know that [Hillary Clinton sent a meme to Donald Trump to delete his account](http://www.theverge.com/2016/6/9/11895760/hillary-clinton-donald-trump-delete-your-account-twitter). And I've read [an article about this](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/delete-your-account) on knowyourmeme.com, that this meme has been around since 2008, but gained momentum around 2015. But I still can't get *why* this is such an interesting meme. I don't find it particularly interesting at all. It feels like just an empty and very, very ordinary words to me. Unlike some of other memes like "Shut up and take my money!". Well, maybe if the meme was "Shut up and delete your account!" I may find it funny or at least interesting. Can you explain from your perspective, why this "delete your account" sentence is funny or interesting enough to be a meme?

Comment: As it stands, this does not seem to be a question about learning English. You might want to edit your post to make it clear why it is [on topic](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @probablyme if it is not, is there any other stack exchange network where this question is probably more appropriate?

Comment: @probablyme, why do you think it is unrelated to this community? The OP wants to know why _"delete your account"_ is funny in the given context. Seems like a straightforward comprehension question to me.

Comment: @VarunKN I guess I just didn't read it that way. Asking about why something is funny just doesn't seem to be a question about learning English. But I guess you might be saying that interpretation is too strict.

Comment: Sometimes I just like to throw or research question like this because it might helps me to understand some 'hidden meaning' behind a particular sentence, or maybe even gain information about some cultural background, because my native language is not English and not raised in western culture. As it stands, I don't find the "delete your account" funny or interesting, so I asked if there's any hidden meaning behind this sentence that I might miss because I probably does not familiar enough with the background humour culture in the given context to get why it's funny or interesting.

Comment: Maybe you can see this like my effort in understanding context and meaning behind poem, parable, or words of wisdom, only this is with a meme.

Comment: Oh, see if you would have written that, it would have been very clear to me that this is an English learning problem. At first I did not think that you needed help because your English seemed very good.

Comment: @Chen Li Yong As a westerner and an American I don't find the expression/meme *deleted your account* especially interesting either.

Comment: I didn't even think it was a joke... I thought it was sincere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [article](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/delete-your-account) you referenced provides a great explanation

> It can be seen as the online equivalent of other colloquial expressions like "kill yourself" and "go home."

You could imagine that you and a friend are walking around town. Your friend has a huge crush on a cute girl and she happens to be walking towards the two of you. Your friend becomes really nervous and as he is about to say "Hi!" to her, he trips and falls on his face. You know he likes her, and you think he has blown his chance with her. You say

> Dude, kill yourself.

In other words, he's committed such a huge blunder that he cannot recover from it. It's not possible to get with this girl so there is no point in living his life.

> Delete your account.

seems to be an equivalent to "kill yourself". Donald Trump has made many disparaging tweets about, among many others, Mexicans and Muslims. In Hillary Clinton's opinion, Trump has made such a huge blunder by posting such absurd tweets that his Twitter/social life is over and that he cannot recover from it. Hence, he should digitally kill himself (delete his account).

I too do not find it funny, so you are not alone. This is not a barrier to learning or mastering English, in case that was your concern.

---

***Addendum:***

I had to rethink my answer.

I looked over the [first article](http://www.theverge.com/2016/6/9/11895760/hillary-clinton-donald-trump-delete-your-account-twitter) and it reports that Trump posted

> Obama just endorsed Crooked Hillary. He wants four more years of Obama — but nobody else does!

Hillary Clinton is tired of hearing Trumps insults and rants. She thinks the Twitterverse would be better without him. So, she responds with "Delete your account." So, like above,

> kill yourself

(digitally, of course). *End your social life so we don't have to hear another word from you!*

Comment: Oooooh, yeah, I understand the "dude, kill yourself". I don't get the "delete your account", but I do get about "*digitally* kill himself". Yeah I know that this is not a barrier in learning English, but in doing this, I can internalise some western culture context (which is greatly different in mine) in order to appreciate some kind of western humours. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I helped. Good luck!